# I can't view the last message when the message's contents fill the screen, can someone help me out?

Tags: lwuit

I am doing an IM application with the lwuit api, In my message form I have an issue, I can't view the last message when the message's contents fill the screen, I have to scroll manually and it is embarrassing.

I have tried everything by my side but still I didn't get the solution.

I hope someone will help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do the same thing as you long time ago but the scrolling of my app became crazy. In this video you can find a similar app and in the description you can find the links to the code. Take a look on them, please.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFClNS5vWQs

Good luck!